# Validating Xml Chef template

Tags: ruby, json, xml, validation, chef-infra

Google hasn't helped me with this:

We just started using Chef deployment. (And I'm embarrassingly new to it)

I have a web.config template that will have variables set by a data bag.

Using some free online tools, I was able to find and fix syntax problems in my data bag. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Is there a way to check the template itself?

Online Xml validation tools like [this one](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/) fail once a Ruby tag <% is found... and this makes sense because it's not valid Xml. Is there a tool/way to validate the Xml in a template so that the Ruby tags are valid?

All I want to know is if syntactically speaking, the file is valid. Logic errors would be dealt with another way... if that makes sense.

Comment: Have you looked at chefspec.

Comment: @StephenKing This looks pretty good... I'll give a shot thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could substitute the values that are supposed to be set by your <%=...%> tags and validate that since your final .xml file won't contain any of those tags if you did your template correct.